# How does the quotient construction of the tensor product imply the tensor product definition of two functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces. To define $V \otimes W$ as a quotient space, let $F$ be the free product of $V$ and $W$, and $R$ the set spanned by
$$(v_1 + v_2, w) - (v_1, w) - (v_2, w)\\
(v, w_1 + w_2) - (v,w_1) - (v, w_2)\\
(sv, w) - s(v,w)\\
(v, sw) - s(v,w)$$
for $v, v_1, v_2 \in V$, $w, w_1, w_2 \in W$, and $s \in \mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. Then $V \otimes W$ is defined as the quotient $F/R$. I understand this approach as demanding what a product "should" satisfy and imposing by using a quotient map.

I am having a hard time understanding how this definition implies the tensor product definition one sees for functions over vector spaces. For example, if $f$ is an $n$-multilinear function on a vector space $V$ and $g$ is an $m$-multilinear function on $V$, then we define
$$(f \otimes g)(v_1, \ldots v_{n+m}) = f(v_1, \ldots v_n) g(v_{n+1}, \ldots v_m).$$

How does the first definition imply the second?

Comment: In the second part of your question you have not yet defined the tensor product. How do you define the tensor product of the function spaces? The tensor product is a vector space together with a bilinear map. So what exactly is this vector space and what exactly is the bilinear map for the "tensor product definition one sees for functions over vector spaces"? That being said, any definition of tensor product that satisfies the universal property is isomorphic to any other, which can be seen by simply applying the universal property.

Comment: Also in your first definition of the tensor product there is a suspicious lack of a bilinear map.

Comment: @jd27 This is the definition of the tensor product as given on Wikipedia. The tensor product of functions is defined by the last formula in my post.

Comment: According to the first sentence in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) wikipedia article (presumably the same one you are referencing), we need a vector space and a bilinear map for the tensor product.  In the wikipedia definition of the tensor product as a quotient space, the tensor product is defined as the vector space $V \otimes W = F/R$ and the bilinear map $ \otimes: V \times W \to V \otimes W$ is defined as the composition of the quotient map $ F \to F/R$ and the map that sends $(v,w)$ to the function that is 1 on $(v,w)$ and zero else. You have omitted it.

Comment: And by that logic you have not defined the tensor product of functions in the second part of your post yet, since you have neither supplied a vector space nor a bilinear map.

Comment: @jd27 Oh yes I see now, thank you for pointing that out. Why do we need this additional vector space of functions (that have a finite number of nonzero values and $(v,w) \mapsto 1$  and zero otherwise)? Why is this needed to define a vector space such that the Cartesian product $V \times W$ is a basis for the vector space?

Comment: basicly we want a vector space $F$ for which $V \times W$ is (or can be identified with) a basis of $F$. $F$ is also called the free vector space (over $V\times W$), you can build the free vector space for any set. See for example [here](https://planetmath.org/FreeVectorSpaceOverASet) for more. Finally we want this vector space so we can build "the right" quotient space from it (so that the universal property will be satisfied by the quotient map). We can build the right quotient, because of the universal property of the free vector space. But really this is material for a new question.

Comment: Also see [here](https://benrbray.com/static/notes/tensor-algebra_5aug19.pdf) for the free vector space and more on the quotient space tensor product construction. It explains everything i was talking about in my previous comment.

Comment: @jd27 I think I got it now, we need to use these functions so that we can take linear combinations of elements of an arbitrary set and the easiest way to do that is by mapping them to $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or something similar). Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign $\otimes$ is very overloaded and may mean different things in different context. This is partly because there are various constructions of the tensor product which are applicable in different generality, and partly because the sign $\otimes$ is used for different purposes related to tensors — for example, the tensor product of vector spaces, the tensor product of vectors, and the tensor product of linear maps are all denoted with the same sign.

The essence of tensor product is its universal property: For every bilinear map $B\colon V \times W \to X$ there is a unique linear map $A\colon V \otimes W \to X$ such that $B(v, w) = A(v \otimes w)$. To construct the tensor product we need to specify the tensor product space $V \otimes W$ and the way to implement the tensor product of vectors $(v, w) \mapsto v \otimes w$, which is a bilinear map.

The first definition in your post is a general definition which works for all vector spaces. As you say, it is constructed specifically so that the defined tensor product of vectors is bilinear.

The second definition is specifically for multilinear maps. Denote by $M^k(V)$ the set of all $k$-multilinear maps on $V$. Consider the map $M^n(V) \times M^m(V) \to M^{n + m}(V)$ which sends $(f, g)$ to $h$ defined as $$h(x_1, \dots, x_{n+m}) = f(x_1, \dots, x_n) g(x_{n + 1}, \dots, x_{n + m})$$
It is bilinear, so we can also see it as a linear map $M^n(V) \otimes M^m(V) \to M^{n + m}(V)$ sending $f \otimes g$ to $h$. Slightly abusing the notation, we say that we view $f \otimes g$ as the multilinear map on $m + n$ arguments and write the second definition.

For finite-dimensional spaces the map $M^n(V) \otimes M^m(V) \to M^{n + m}(V)$ is actually an isomorphism. Because $M^1(V) = V^*$, in this context we can actually *identify* $M^n(V)$ with $(V^*)^{\otimes n}$. It is often very convenient to say that multilinear map *is* a tensor, not just *has* a corresponding tensor. In this terminology, the tensor product in your second definition becomes an honest tensor product in $(V^*)^{\otimes (m + n)} = (V^*)^{\otimes n} \otimes (V^*)^{\otimes m}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!